# Live CD doesn't boot correctly!

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, live-cd

I just tried to reinstall my Ubuntu 12.04 System so I put in my live-CD (64bit) and did a reboot.
Then my computer detects it and it wants to boot from it.

Shortly you can see two lines of text and then it stucks on a blackscreen. In the top left corner you can see a "command-line" courser. A courser as it can be seen in the virtual terminal of Ubuntu (Ctrl+Alt+F1).

Answer (score 0):

If you were originally able to boot from this live CD to install Ubuntu, then the CD may have become damaged and you should make a new CD/DVD or USB flash drive.

Comment: I already tested 3 different CDs/DVDs. ;-)

Comment: Did you originally boot and install from an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS live CD/DVD? If not (for example, if you upgraded to 12.04 from a previous release), you should **(1)** [MD5 test your `.iso` image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) and **(2)** try [booting with the `nomodeset` boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132).